# grails - spring security - get save attribute doesn't work

Tags: grails, spring-security, login-control

I all,

After an authentication I want to redirect the user to the address specified in the url.
For that I implement this code:

In the loginController:

```
def auth = {        
   def savedRequest = session.getAttribute(WebAttributes.SAVED_REQUEST)  

...}
```

and in config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true

grails.plugins.springsecurity.onAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->

def savedRequest = session.getAttribute(WebAttributes.SAVED_REQUEST);
String requestUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl()
}

grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = requestUrl
```

After submitting the login I have this error:

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException:
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   groovy.util.ConfigObject.getAttribute() is applicable for argument
>   types: (groovy.util.ConfigObject) values: [[:]]
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) root cause
>
> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   groovy.util.ConfigObject.getAttribute() is applicable for argument
>   types: (groovy.util.ConfigObject) values: [[:]]
>     script1379418399441191405188$_run_closure3.doCall(script1379418399441191405188.groovy:154)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) note The full stack trace of
>   the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.25 logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring security should do this automatically unless you have it turned off.

This will take the user to a url if they didnt specify one or if the setting is off after a successful login

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = ""
```

This setting you can simply not specify or set to false. This states that every time the user logs in they will be redirected to the default target url regardless of what page they attempted to access before they got the authorization request. So, if I understand you correct, set this to false or dont specify it at all and the functionality you want should work.

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault=true
```

Comment: You're right, so its more simple that I thought.
But I comment this line:
//grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = "".
Because double quote is not supported.

Comment: I just used the quotes as a placeholder - I don't actually have it that way in my config.